# Running adb.exe command from maven 3.0.5

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is it possible to run adb.exe commands from maven. For example I want to run **adb shell instrument -e classname#testcasename -w packagename/instrumenation**. I need to run this command in maven is it possible?? Do i need to specify it in the pom.xml file or it can be run directly by specifying the command-line argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**Maven Exec Plugin**](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) to execute `cmd` commands.

In the snippet below (add it to a `pom.xml`), the command `ping` with the argument `8.8.8.8` will be executed every time you do a `mvn install`:

```
<project>
...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>My Command Runner</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>ping</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>8.8.8.8</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
</project>
```

In your case, the inner `configuration` would be something around:

```
<configuration>
    <executable>adb </executable>
    <arguments>
        <argument>shell</argument>
        <argument>instrument</argument>
        <argument>-e</argument>
        <argument>classname#testcasename</argument>
        <argument>-w</argument>
        <argument>packagename/instrumenation</argument>
    </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Make sure you bind it to the phase you really need. The example above, as said, is bound to the `mvn install` - meaning the command will be executed when someone runs that (`install`) phase.

Comment: I am doing this in windows OS and on an emulator. There I am getting /system/bin/sh: instrument: not found error.